# inequality with three variables and condition

Tags: inequality, polynomials, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

If $a$,$b$ and $c$ positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=1$, prove $\dfrac{b^2}{a+b^2}+\dfrac{c^2}{b+c^2}+\dfrac{a^2}{c+a^2} \geqslant \dfrac{3}{4}$. I have tried several methods to solve this,but can't get any result. Any idea?

Comment: i think $a,b,c$ are positive

Comment: of course,i will change task now

Comment: from where does this come?

Comment: If it is helpful, $\frac{3}{4}$ is attained where $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 3):

By C-S and Vasc we obtain $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{a^2+c}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^4}{a^4+a^2c(a+b+c)}\geq\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4+a^3c+a^2b^2+a^2bc)}\geq$

$\geq\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4+a^2b^2+a^2bc)+\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{3}}=\frac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(4a^4+5a^2b^2+3a^2bc)}$.

Id est, it remains to prove that $4(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}(4a^4+5a^2b^2+3a^2bc)$, which is $\sum\limits_{cyc}c^2(a-b)^2\geq0$. Done!

Comment: It is a good answer, but it is quite cryptical. I bet *C-S* is Cauchy-Schwarz, but what it *Vasc*? To improve the rendering would be a good idea, too, IMHO.

Comment: The Vasc;'s inequality it's the following. $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\geq3(a^3c+b^3a+c^3b)$. It's true because $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-3(a^3c+b^3a+c^3b)=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-b^2+ab-2ac+bc)^2\geq0$.