# If $a+b+c=1$ and a,b,c ＞0 prove $\dfrac{b^2}{a+b^2}+\dfrac{c^2}{b+c^2}+\dfrac{a^2}{c+a^2} \geqslant \dfrac{3}{4}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

If $a+b+c=1$ and a,b,c＞0 prove $\dfrac{b^2}{a+b^2}+\dfrac{c^2}{b+c^2}+\dfrac{a^2}{c+a^2} \geqslant \dfrac{3}{4}$. I tried with CS Engel form,homogenization but ina anyway i can't prove inequality. Can someone helpp?

Comment: You asked the identical question three years ago (and got an answer) ...

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong for real numbers.

For positive variables by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{a^2+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2(a+b)^2}{(c(a+b+c)+a^2)(a+b)^2}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+ab)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+c^2+ac+bc)(a+b)^2}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$4\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+ab)\right)^2\geq3\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+c^2+ac+bc)(a+b)^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4-a^3b+5a^3c+3a^2b^2-8a^2bc)\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4-a^3b)\geq0$$ by Rearrangement;
$$\sum_{cyc}a^3c\geq\sum_{cyc}a^2bc$$ it's
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}\geq\sum_{cyc}a,$$ which is true by Rearrangement again and
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2b^2-a^2bc)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}c^2(a-b)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: +1 for the good efforts, even though duplicate.

Comment: @Macavity: Michael already answered the original question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602340/42969 :)

Comment: @Macavity Thank you! I usually don't remember what I proved.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: It is quite easy with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cdfrac%7Bb%5E2%7D%7Ba%2Bb%5E2%7D%2B%5Cdfrac%7Bc%5E2%7D%7Bb%2Bc%5E2%7D%2B%5Cdfrac%7Ba%5E2%7D%7Bc%2Ba%5E2%7D%20%5Cgeqslant%20%5Cdfrac%7B3%7D%7B4%7D%24&p=1) – it takes less than a minute to find that this question has been asked and answered before.